# Flask SQLAlchemy filter records by a field value and a foreign key relationship

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Just started using SQLAlchemy with flask and I can't figure out how to write this one query.
The models I use:

```
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    role = db.Column(db.String(5), nullable=False, default='user')
    # This field represents the many files one user can have
    files = db.relationship('Files', backref='owner', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.password}', '{self.role}', '{self.files}')"

class Files(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    filename = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True, nullable=False)
    date_modified = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Files('{self.filename}', '{self.owner_id}', '{self.date_modified}')"
```

EXPLANATION: A user has a one to many relationship with many files that he owns.

So what I have is a **username** and a **filename** and I'm trying to **extract the specific user's file that has a matching filename.**

Many users --> A single user --> The user's files --> The file with the specific name I need.

I've tried to find a solution but felt overwhelmed by all the different functions and ways of querying.

What I had tried already is to get all files with the specific filename assuming the filename field is unique. But even this didn't work:

```
requested_file = User.query.join(Files).filter(Files.filename == searched_filename).first()
```

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'
```

I would appreciate any help with this

Comment: Most likely you "shadowed" the `Files` by assigning it to `None` somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
requested_files = Files.query.filter_by(filename==searched_filename, owner_id=user_id).all()
```

And don't mess up, change your

`files = db.relationship('Files', backref='owner', lazy=True)`

`owner_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)`

into

`files = db.relationship('Files', backref='user', lazy=True)`

`user_id= db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)`

Meanwhile, the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'` is because there is no `Files` in your Files table since you already joined `Files`. Make sure you migrated with model and there is data in db.

Comment: Thank you this worked, seems like a very simple and easy to understand  solution! I approached it from the wrong direction, I tried accessing the user table and from there the files table through querying while I could have just queried the files table.